# Why all particles in Stationary waves are in same phase between two successive nodes?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, superposition

Consider the stationary wave equation 
$y=2acos(kx)sin (wt)$

Why do we say that all particles between two successive nodes have same phase at an given instant ?

Shouldn't there be a phase difference between any two particles because of their different x co-ordinates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your equation $y$ is the displacement of a particle from and equilibrium position distance $x$ from a origin at time $t$.

A standing is often drawn as follows.

[image]

Now this diagram is a series of superimposed wave profiles.
A wave profile shows the displacement of the particles at a given time $t$.
It is a photograph of a wave taken at a time $t$.

If one separates the wave profiles one gets a sequence as shown below.

[image]

Note the particles are moving in phase with a period $T=\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}$ with their amplitude modulated by the function $2a\sin kx$.

Between two nodes the sign of $\sin kx$ is the same only its value changes and so the displacement of the particles between two nodes is always in the same direction with only their displacement being different.
This means that the particles between two nodes are moving in phase.

Just look at the black waveform in the animation below.

[image]

Comment: I am confused about the definition of phase, Can you please explain it in simple words ?

Comment: All moving together in the same direction at the same part of their motion. For example in the diagram above at a time equal to half a period  between two adjacent nodes the particles all have their  maximum displacement in the negative direction.

Comment: How do you understand about whether particles are moving in phase or not in case of a traveling wave ?

Comment: Every wavelength apart the particles are moving in phase. They will all be at exactly the same point in their oscillatory motion. That is how wavelength is defined.

Comment: @VinayakAgarwal Phase simply means the argument of some trig function, so $\phi$ in $\cos(\phi)$, $\sin(\phi)$, or $e^{i\phi}$. Usually, the trig function in question is obvious. In  your case, they mean the $kx$ in $\cos(kx)$ -- it can't be $\omega t$, since they state "at a given instant".

Comment: @led23head But isn't $x$ in $cos(kx)$ different for different particles on string?

Comment: @VinayakAgarwal Yeah, you're right. I was backwards. They're not talking about the $kx$ in $\cos(kx)$, they're talking about the $\omega t$ in $\sin(\omega t)$.

Comment: @led23head Why don't we talk about the $kx$ term ?

Comment: @VinayakAgarwal The point here is that each "particle" (i.e. constant $x$) is moving up and down exactly in sync (i.e. in phase) with all other particles. The only difference is how high they're going (i.e. amplitude). In that sense, the $\cos(kx)$ just factors into the amplitude for the particle at position $x$. As opposed to a traveling wave, (e.g. $\cos(kx-\omega t)$) for which each "particle" is at a different phase. (Except of  course, two particles $2 \pi/k$  apart have the same phase.)